# copy database from Mongo Cloud Atlas to local Mac

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo cloud atlas with a database which is used by a meteor app hosted on AWS.
How can I copy the database currently hosed on Mongo Cloud Atlas to my local MacBook? Thanks

Comment: `mongodump` may be the best method.

Comment: please give command: This one failed, $mongodump -h "mongodb://cluster0-shard-00-00-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-oko1k.mongodb.net:27017/admin?replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0" -d dbName -u xyz -p abc
-bash: !3: event not found

Comment: `-h` does not accept MongoDB URI string. Use `--uri` instead. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/ for more details regarding `mongodump` options.

Comment: I am getting "-bash: !3: event not found", Are you able to give the full command in an answer? Thanks